# Is there a way in Kotlin/Java/Android where you can dynamically get a list and display it based on an Intent Extra

Tags: android, list, kotlin, fragment, webapi

I am trying to build a sports app, and I have created my activities and fragments.
Currently I am using a String Array from the String Resources file to get a list of Team names, and when you click on said team, I launch another activity to show you team info. I am currently working on getting the schedule display. I really would like to do this dynamically by getting the information for the team based on the users selection of a team from the list. Also I would like to try and get the information, possibly from a free WebAPI and then process the api and display the teams schedule in said team schedule tab when selected.

This is my team schedule fragment, and I just have it grabbing the team name list from the string resources again because I wanted to make sure the activity/fragment was launched

```
    package com.adonaubauer.myapplicationone.ui.main

    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
    import androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment
    import com.adonaubauer.myapplicationone.R

    class NflTeamScheduleFragment : ListFragment() {

        var mNum = 0

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            mNum = arguments?.getInt("num") ?: 1
            val layout = R.layout.nfl_team_schedule_layout

            // Need to get all the schedules for the teams so it changes for each team
            // Need to change the names of Oakland Raiders -> Las Vegas Raiders
            // Need to change the name of Washington Redskins -> Washington Football Team

            when (activity?.intent?.extras?.get("Team Name")) {
                "Arizona Cardinals" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it, 
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Atlanta Falcons" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it,   
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Baltimore Ravens" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it,  
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Buffalo Bills" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it,     
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Carolina Panthers" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it, 
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Chicago Bears" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it,     
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Cleveland Browns" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it,  
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Dallas Cowboys" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it,    
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Denver Broncos" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it,    
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Detroit Lions" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it,     
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Green Bay Packers" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it, 
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Houston Texans" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it,    
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Indianapolis Colts" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it, 
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Jacksonville Jaguars" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it, 
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Kansas City Chiefs" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it, 
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Los Angeles Chargers" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it, 
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Los Angeles Rams" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it,  
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Miami Dolphins" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it,    
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Minnesota Vikings" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it, 
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "New England Patriots" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it, 
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "New Orleans Saints" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it, 
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "New York Giants" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it,   
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "New York Jets" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it,     
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Oakland Raiders" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it,   
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Philadelphia Eagles" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it, 
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Pittsburgh Steelers" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it, 
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "San Francisco 49ers" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it, 
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Seattle Seahawks" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it,  
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Tampa Bay Buccaneers" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it, 
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Tennessee Titans" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it,  
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }
                "Washington Redskins" -> listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it,  
                    layout, resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }

            }

        //listAdapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String> (it, layout, 
        // resources.getStringArray(R.array.nfl_team_names)) }

        }

        companion object {
           /**
            *
            * The newInstance method will create new NflTeamsFragment objects and
            * return them with arguments
            *
            * @param num
            * @return
            */
            @JvmStatic
            fun newInstance(num: Int): NflTeamScheduleFragment {

                val nflTeamScheduleFragment = NflTeamScheduleFragment()
                val args = Bundle()
                args.putInt("num", num)
                nflTeamScheduleFragment.arguments = args
                return nflTeamScheduleFragment

            }

        }

    }
```

So, say for the first line in the When loop, the team is the Arizona Cardinals, I would like to display a list of their schedule in the team schedule tab. Now, I believe I could go in and create a string array and have the string items of each game and display it that way. But I would like to try and do it dynamically using a WebAPI so I didn't have to type each teams schedule out in a string array in the Resource File.

Comment: In the when loop you hard coded the names of the teams. This is wrong to begin with. And then you retrieve te same list for every team. That does not make sense.

Comment: So use a WebAPI. Steps I'd recommend: 1. Add Retrofit and kotlin coroutines as dependencies. 2. Find the api you want and write a function for it in retrofit. 3. Write a data class to deserialize the json data from the api. 4. Add a deserializer plugin to retrofit (I recommend kotlinx-serialization) 5. Call that function via a coroutine and do what you want with the data

Comment: Blackapps, I just have it getting the list of names for the teams as a test to make sure it worked. I am looking for steps on how to get a schedule for each team when the user clicks on a team on the previous activity.
Carson, do you know of any free webapi's, do you know of any ways I could create one myself?